# GlobalConfiguration - Attempt to access field '<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2' failed

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am getting this error when setting the Dependency Resolver.

Code:

> GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);

Error:

> Attempt by method 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration..cctor()' to access field 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2' failed.

What am I missing here?

All solutions posted involve installing latest version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -IncludePrerelease

However, I already have all the latest versions of required assemblies, and I'm still getting this error.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Packages were installed but apparently some references were taken from the GAC instead of from the NuGet package folders.

These were manually removed, and I added the references in the packages folder and it worked.

(There should be a NuGet feature to "clean up" references so that they take from the packages folder instead of elsewhere.)

Comment: Same issue - some references were pointing not to the \packages folder, so I deleted them and re-added via the \packages folder, and the "Attempt by method 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration..cctor()' to access field 'System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.CS$<>9__CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate2' failed" error disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

I solve this issue by installing Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Solution link: https://www.niceonecode.com/Question/20222/The-type-initializer-for-System.Web.Http.-GlobalConfiguration-threw-an-exceptio

I have the same problem which is solved by the solution to it.

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Pre
It will include a pre-release version.